# kafka-connect rest api timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, aws-fargate

Running confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.5.1 with Debezium postgresql source connector in AWS Fargate.

On the first run, there are no issues. Replication slot with name 'debezium' created in RDS and database changes are written into Kafka topic.

I want to test the failure scenario, so,

- I manually stopped the Fargate kafka-connect task.
- Fargate created new task.
- Once the task is up, I listed the connectors with
  http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors/, surprisingly, the existing
  connector configuration which I created is present.
- However,
  http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors/source-debezium-01 and
  http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors/source-debezium-01/status are
  timing out.(kafka-connect is replaced with NLB domain) Couldn't find any logs in Cloudwatch.
- Tried enabling
  debug log,
  https://rmoff.net/2020/01/16/changing-the-logging-level-for-kafka-connect-dynamically/,
  however after enabling debug log also, nothing shows up in the logs.
- Found this one,
  https://rmoff.net/2019/11/29/kafka-connect-request-timed-out/,
  however, I run AWS MSK with 3 brokers and offset topic replication
  factor is 3. So this shouldn't be an issue in my case.
- When I delete the replication slot in RDS and recreate new task in Fargate,
  kafka-connect creates new replication slot and it starts working.

Questions,

- How does the connector configuration is persisted since I don't have persistence storage in Fargate task?
- Why does the new task doesn't work and why I have to delete the replication slot?

Comment: I was missing heartbeat topic in the MSK, once I create it, new task comes online automatically. Still want to hear from experts for the questions I asked.

Comment: "How does the connector configuration is persisted since I don't have persistence storage in Fargate task?" -> Kafka Connect in Distributed mode uses Kafka itself to store state. Have a look at https://rmoff.net/2019/11/22/common-mistakes-made-when-configuring-multiple-kafka-connect-workers/ as it may be you're hitting issues around hostnames etc

Comment: Thanks Robin, In fargate I am using awsvpc networking mode, so tasks' IP will be ENI's IP of host. I don't have any issues with hostnames.